# Delete duplicate rows according to condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL database. I have the data like below.

```
   id      name1              name2            modified_date
   - - - - -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
   40      Balfe           | Pat            | 2010-10-01 17:48:44.804823 
   41      Battigan        | David          |                            
   42      Balfe           | Pat            | 2010-10-01 12:46:49.627593 
   44      Balfe           | Pat            | 2010-10-04 14:04:28.72415  
   45      Balfe           | Pat            | 
   46      Balfe           | Pat            | 2010-10-01 17:30:39.193153 
   47      Balfe           | Pat            |
```

I want to delete some rows from the table. The conditions to delete are:

1. It will delete duplicate records with `modified_date = Null`
        --> one copy of duplicate records should not be deleted.
2. Records with modified date should not be deleted although they are duplicate.

From the table above, the record with id `47` **or** `45` should be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one should delete all records with `modified_date Is Null`, where another record with the same `name1` and `name2` exists, which also has `modified_date Is Null`.

The record with the lowest `id` will not be deleted.

```
Delete From your_table t1
Where modified_date Is Null
And Exists ( Select 1
             From your_table t2
             Where t2.name1 = t1.name1
               And t2.name2 = t2.name2
               And t2.modified_date Is Null
               And t2.id < t1.id
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, something like:

```
DELETE FROM tablename 
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT id 
                FROM tablename 
                WHERE modified_date = Null)
```

Not sure if PostgreSQL supports subqueries with an IN statement though.

Comment: Would have to be `Is Null` instead of `= Null`, but then it would delete all records where it is `Null`, without keeping one record...